# SQLCommand syntax error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing to request some help on my c# syntax.  I keep getting syntax in "sda.Fill(dt);" and I can not figure out the reason why.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;
  using System.Configuration;

  public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string query = "select distinct Price_type from Price";
        DataTable dt = GetData(query);
        ddlPrice.DataSource = dt;
        ddlPrice.DataTextField = "Price_type";
        ddlPrice.DataValueField = "Price_type";
        ddlPrice.DataBind();

        ddlPrice2.DataSource = dt;
        ddlPrice2.DataTextField = "Price_type";
        ddlPrice2.DataValueField = "Price_type";
        ddlPrice2.DataBind();
        ddlPrice2.Items[1].Selected = true;
    }
}

     protected void Compare(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string query = string.Format("select price, date from Price where Price_type = '{0}' order by date)", ddlPrice.SelectedItem.Value);
       DataTable dt = GetData(query);

    string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
    decimal[] y = new decimal[dt.Rows.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]);
    }
        LineChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.LineChartSeries { Name = ddlPrice.SelectedItem.Value, Data = y });

        query = string.Format("select price, date from Price where Price_type = '{0}' order by date)", ddlPrice2.SelectedItem.Value);
    dt = GetData(query);

     y = new decimal[dt.Rows.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]);
    }
         LineChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.LineChartSeries { Name = ddlPrice2.SelectedItem.Value, Data = y });
    LineChart1.CategoriesAxis = string.Join(",", x);

        LineChart1.ChartTitle = string.Format("{0} and {1} Order Distribution", ddlPrice.SelectedItem.Value, ddlPrice2.SelectedItem.Value);
    LineChart1.Visible = true;
}

private static DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bwic testConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. VS keeps a displaying "sda.Fill(dt);" as syntax error in the "GetData" function. I can not figure out why. Apology for the unclear information. Many thanks.

Comment: Ok, but what is the exact error message in the Output Window? That's the important part :)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @john Sorry I did not know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` might be a reserved keyword, depending of the version you use. Write `[date]` instead. And this

```
"select price, date from Price where Price_type = '{0}' order by date)"
```

should be

```
"select price, date from Price where Price_type = '{0}' order by date"
```

Comment: Dear @Linus, Thank you for your suggestion. I am sorry to say your suggestion did not resolve the error - "Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ')'.". Thank you.

Comment: @user1574185, well, there is no start `(`, but an end `)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time.  I am kinda new into C#, hence the silly mistakes, sorry.  Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
    {
        using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing syntactically wrong with your `GetData()` method as shown in your original post. You might try commenting out the entire body of the method and then start uncommenting things one at a time to isolate the actual problem.

But it apparently seems that you don't have a syntax error: you have invalid SQL. The SQL you are trying to execute is:

```
select price, date from Price where Price_type = '{0}' order by date)
```

It has two things wrong with it:

- The closing (right) parenthesis at the end is your syntax error, and
- the parameter should not be enclosed in quotes.

Your SQL should look something like

```
select price, date from Price where Price_type = {0} order by date
```

Your method should look something like  this:

```
private static DataTable GetData1( string query , string p0 )
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bwic testConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
  using ( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection( constr ) )
  using ( SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand() )
  using ( SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd) )
  {
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter() ;
    p.Value = p0Value ;
    cmd.Parameters.Add( p ) ;
    con.Open();
    sda.Fill( dt );
    con.Close();
  }
  return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use brackets twice - in SELECT clause and in ORDER BY clause too.

Comment: Can you please write the whole query here? Please read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

in your code bolck as below

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

change it to

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

The problem here is that you havent opened any connection before filling.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I added the open connection but I am sorry to say, I am still getting the same error ---- Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't opened a connection anywhere. You must open the connection before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

If your whole class code is really this, you are missing a closing } at the end of the file for the

```
 public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
```

declaration.